# Redirect all the traffic from multiple domains to single domain using htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I have hosted multiple websites on my server all sharing the same code base having one htaccess.

I need something like this.

> if (domainname != example.com)  redirect to example.com

if there any way of handling this from htaccess

used the following but still it is not working

```
RewriteCond !^(.*)$ https://example1.com/$1 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: As per @krt I used. Still not working
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://talentpark.net/$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www[.].+$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !srishakthi.org$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://talentpark.net/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   RewriteBase /

Answer (score 2):

Adding the below apache rewrite rules should do the trick for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# first redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# second redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above rules will do a 301 redirect of:

`domain.com` --> `newdomain.com`

and

`example1.com` --> `example2.com`

For each domain you want to be redirected use seperate `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`.

Comment: does this redirect the https:// too. I only need to redirect https

Comment: I've edited my answer, it will now redirect to `https`.

Comment: I am a bit confused here, does not the '**!**' mean that if the url is not **domain.com** then redirect. does it also not mean that if the url is **domain.com** "do not redirect"

Comment: If I am right the above code redirects [http://domain.com] to [https://newdomain.com]. How to redirect **only** the [https://domain.com] to [https://newdomain.com]